# Can I print from a SOAP API?

Tags: c#, api, reporting-services, printing, report

I've been tasked with creating a .NET application that would live on a print server and receive print notifications from client computers. The app will receive a request to print an SSRS report document, request containing backing stored procedure name, database connection string, report file name, and other details. The app needs to reply with success or fail, along with error details as applicable.

The application won't leverage the SQL Server Web Service. Rather the reports will be rdlc files on the file system, manipulated by my API.

I'm thinking this might be best fulfilled via a C# SOAP API. However, I'm concerned that since it's web-based, it won't have access to the server's printers.

Before I go down this rabbit hole, can anyone tell me if my API will be able to print? And I'm open to suggestions for better ways to handle this.

TIA!

Comment: Generally people print what they download. Do you want to have a print command in your custom code?

Comment: Ross, the customer will be printing custom reports that display results from SQL database queries. The reports will reside on the print server. There's no downloading. There will be multiple apps that can call this print service. The service will do the print, with no print dialog appearing. Make sense?

Comment: Then you only need to render the report using ReportExecution api and place them somewhere to be consumed?

Comment: Doesn't that require Report Server, though? Customers won't have report server. This has to be independent.

Comment: You can't render a remote report without ssrs being installed.

Comment: Can you pull down the .rdl file and render it on an ssrs server and then send the output to the print server? ...That would be difficult though because any data access would have to be accessible to the box the report is rendered on.

Comment: Maybe have the reporting web service as part of your normal app where SSRS is installed. This generates the report and puts in a queue for printing (could be as simple as a blob in a table of pending reports to print). Then the print server just needs a Windows service that polls this queue and prints anything waiting for print. This decouples report production from printing.

Comment: Well, thanks Ross and Chris for the input. I think it's time to push back on the higher-ups. The no report server requirement came from them. I think my answer is that the customer will need to have report server to accomplish this. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the feedback I got in the comments, I'm going to say this can't be done with the requirements given.